# replace() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find the first day of the month in python

```html
<form method="GET" action="">
  <input name="range2" type="date"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

```
to_date = request.GET.get('range2')    
from_date = to_date.replace(day=1)
```

but i got this error : replace() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is `to_date`? Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: to_date = request.GET.get('range2')

Comment: See definition of [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace). `to_date` is a string (`str`), since it's what your HTTP request is submitting. It's not a date (`datetime.date`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type is `to_date`? Do `print(type(to_date))` - if its a `str`, it is going to use str.replace, which takes no kwargs. This would throw an error here. :)

Comment: OK, so based on your answer above, I'd say you're returned a string and therefore, indeed replace doesn't take arguments.